# I need to add content to each Rowdatapacket

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to add the poblacion result to casas, casas is composed by diferents rowdatapackets one for each diferent id from the Database. I need to add each poblacion to each diferent casas

```
router.get('/', async (req,res) => {
  const casas=  await pool.query('SELECT * FROM PISOS');
  const poblacion = await pool.query('SELECT nombre FROM poblaciones, pisos WHERE pisos.id_poblacion = ? and poblaciones.id= ? ', [casas[0].id_poblacion, casas[0].id_poblacion] );
  casas.push(poblacion[0].nombre);
   res.render('casas/list', { casas, poblacion: poblacion[0]});
});
```

`casas.push()` doesnt do what i want it just creates another array inside casas, i want to add poblacion to each diferent casas

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're looking for...

instead of:

```
casas.push(poblacion[0].nombre)
```

try appending the nombre to each object within the casas array:

```
casas.forEach(obj => obj.nombre = poblacion[0].nombre)
```

Comment: It does what i want but now it  adds the same poblacion to each casas. Each casas has a different poblacion

Comment: That is outside the scope of your question... however, I would encourage you to modify the poblacion query to include the pisos.id, that way you can map each nombre to each casas by pisos.id